# operator <= cannot be applied to operands of type string and string

Tags: c#, string, datetime

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(ModCommon.sqldate(ModCommon.SetDate(JoinDate.Text))).ToString("yyyyMMdd") <= "19000101")
{
    dtpJoinDate.Text = "";
}
```

i do not know what is wrong with my Code..
It Gives Error that.."operator <= cannot be applied to operands of type string and string"

Comment: Error message is clear. You are comparing `string` and `string` with  `<=` operator. What are you try do exactly? Are you try to compare `DateTime` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [`<=` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx063734.aspx) with strings. Because `String` class doesn't overload `<=` operator. Except for operator overloading, this operator can be use with numeric types and enum types *only*.

I assume you try to compare your `DateTime` values in your case. If so, you can compare like;

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
if(Convert.ToDateTime(ModCommon.sqldate(ModCommon.SetDate(JoinDate.Text))) <= dt)
{
     dtpJoinDate.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says every thing.
You are connverting date to string and checking if it's lesser than any other string.
Can you answer : IF "ABC"<="abc"

use :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("19000101", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
if (Convert.ToDateTime(ModCommon.sqldate(ModCommon.SetDate(JoinDate.Text))) <= dt)
{
    dtpJoinDate.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Would be better to use explicit initialize your second `DateTime` value like `new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)` because there is no guarantee to parse your `19000101` string without specify any `IFormatProvider`.

Comment: you are right :) I just tested it and it's a shame it didn't work. :(, I'll rectify it :). Mind if I copy a lil snippet from yours :P

Comment: string.Compare("ABC", "abc") can answer if ABC <= abc or not right? than why <= cant? )

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the string date into a datetime, double or int before testing it.

```
DateTime.Parse
```

could be useful